# Random Number Guessing Game Answers 0

Tags: c#, random

I am creating a random number guessing game where the user sets the maximum number they want to guess from. I have figured out most of the code, the problem that I seem to be getting is that after setting the maximum number and beginning to guess the answer is always 0. Any tips on how to adjust my code so that the answer is a number within the range and not 0?

```
class Program
{

    public static int SelectedNumber = 0;
    public static Random ran = new Random();
    public static bool GameOver = false;
    public static int UserMaxValue = 0; 
    public static string decision;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int UserNumber;
        SelectedNumber = ran.Next(0, UserMaxValue);

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What is the maximum number you want to guess from?");
            UserMaxValue = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Select a number between 1 and {0}!", UserMaxValue);
                UserNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                GuessNumber(UserNumber);
            } while (GameOver == false);
        } while (GameOver == false);
    }

    public static void GuessNumber(int UserNumber)
    {

        if (UserNumber < SelectedNumber)
            Console.WriteLine("Your number is wrong, please try again!");
        else if (UserNumber > SelectedNumber)
            Console.WriteLine("Your Number is wrong, please try again!");
        //else if (UserNumber == 0)
        //    Console.WriteLine("Your Number is wrong, please try again!");
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Yay! You got the right number. Do you want to play again? (y/n) ", decision);
            decision = Console.ReadLine();

            if (decision == "n")
                GameOver = true;
            else
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("What is the maximum number you want to guess from?");
                    UserMaxValue = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                    do
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Select a number between 1 and {0}!", UserMaxValue);
                        UserNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        GuessNumber(UserNumber);
                    } while (GameOver == false);
                } while (GameOver == false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have the following lines, in this order (I'm omitting the rest in between):

```
public static int UserMaxValue = 0; 
// ...
SelectedNumber = ran.Next(0, UserMaxValue);
// ...
Console.WriteLine("What is the maximum number you want to guess from?");
        UserMaxValue = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

You have to ask the user for UserMaxValue before you can correctly set SelectedNumber.

Comment: Additionally, the ran.Next is only ever called once, it's supposed to be called every time user ask to play again.

Answer (score 1):

Had to do some corrections on your code. Added some comments for the changes.
You better add error handling on the user input.

UPDATE: Added error handling for invalid input.

```
class Program
{
    public static int SelectedNumber = 0;
    public static Random ran = new Random();
    public static bool GameOver = false;
    public static int UserMaxValue = 0;        

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int UserNumber = 0;
        bool playAgain = false;
        do
        {
            bool isUserMaxValueValid = false;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("What is the maximum number you want to guess from?");
                isUserMaxValueValid = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out UserMaxValue);
            } while (!isUserMaxValueValid);

            SelectedNumber = ran.Next(1, UserMaxValue); // Re-assign SelectedNumber for every new max number input. Random number start changed to 1 to avoid 0 value for SelectedNumber

            do
            {
                bool isUserNumberValid = false;
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Select a number between 1 and {0}!", UserMaxValue);
                    isUserNumberValid = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out UserNumber);
                } while (!isUserNumberValid);

                playAgain = GuessNumber(UserNumber);
                // I changed GameOver to see if the guessing portion is finished or not
            } while (!GameOver); // You don't need to use GameOver == false
        } while (playAgain); // Check if user wants to play again or not
    }


    public static bool GuessNumber(int UserNumber)
    {
        if (UserNumber != SelectedNumber)
        {
            GameOver = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Your number is wrong, please try again!");
        }
        else
        {
            GameOver = true;
            bool isPlayAgainValid = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Yay! You got the right number. Do you want to play again? (y/n)");
            do
            {
                string decision = Console.ReadLine();

                if (decision.Equals("n", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else if (decision.Equals("y", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    break;
                }

                if(!isPlayAgainValid)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter y or n only.");
                }
            } while (!isPlayAgainValid);               


            // I removed redundant code
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The checks for larger/smaller number seems redundant if they end up showing the same message (unless the case in "Number" is deliberate). Either give explicitly different message to guide the user using binary search, or join them in != condition.

Also, using decision as second parameter in ConsoleWriteLine doesn't do anything since the string have no composite format

Comment: I prefer having GuessNumber to return GameOver value and having PlayAgain Decision outside the GameOver loop instead. Also you can shortened `return decision != "n"` for PlayAgain

Comment: I think I also need to use TryParse somewhere in the code in order to give an error message is the user enters something other than a number. I'm just not sure where and how it should be written?

Comment: @j_1311 I updated my answer and added a sample error handling.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are generating the number to guess before you ask the max
have the:

```
 SelectedNumber = ran.Next(1, UserMaxValue);
```

be after the asking for the max:

```
Console.WriteLine("What is the maximum number you want to guess from?");
UserMaxValue = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```